# Hover data on bar graph without plotting text - plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am struggling with something that is probably quite simple.
consider this: I have unit ids with data for each unit id.
I want to construct a bar graph and to be able to select whatever unit id I want.
To do this I chose plotly px. I am constructing the bars according to some range split method (using pd.cut)
The result I have is very close to what I want. 
when I’m hovering on the different units on the graph I see the unit id, range, and exact value
but the text is also plotted on the graph and makes the plot very messy.
I tried to use different px.bar attributed to replacing %{text}% but without success.

Small code that reproduces the plot I have

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px

data = np.random.rand(300)
unit_id = np.random.choice(range(1000), 300, replace=False)
data_tuple = sorted([(str(uid), data) for uid, data in zip(unit_id, data)], key=lambda x: x[1])

y_data = [y[1] for y in data_tuple]
x_data = [i for i in range(1, len(y_data) + 1)]
range_bins = pd.cut(np.array(np.array(y_data).astype(float)), 10)
data_range_lbl = [str(v) for v in range_bins]

sorted_unit_id = [x[0] for x in data_tuple]
unit_id_text = [sorted_unit_id[i] + '<br><b>Value</b>: ' + str(y_data[i]) for i in range(0, len(sorted_unit_id))]
fig = px.bar(x=data_range_lbl, y=[1 for i in range(0, len(data_range_lbl))], text=unit_id_text)

fig.update_layout(dragmode='select')
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=
                  '<b>Die Id</b>: %{text}' +
                  '<br><b>Range</b>: %{x}<br>')
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='container-button-timestamp'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='sample-graph', figure=fig
    ),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050)
```

how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

using `hovertext` did the trick.
removed `text`  from px.bar attributes:
 `fig = px.bar(x=data_range_lbl, y=[1 for i in range(0, len(data_range_lbl))])`
and changed fig.update_traces:

```
fig.update_traces(
    hovertext=unit_id_text,
    hovertemplate=
    '<b>Die Id</b>: %{hovertext}' +
    '<br><b>Range</b>: %{x}<br>')
```